# C++ Blackjack Gameplay

Tags: c++

Alright, so I'm really new to programming, and i'm trying to make a Blackjack game for a class I am taking. I've got the gist of everything so far, but when it comes to the actual gamep lay part, i'm having trouble. When I look at my code, I can't see why my game won't function right. I expect it to be an easier fix than I am seeing, because I usually miss the small things.

```
for(;;)
{
    cout << "1)Bet, 2)Hit or 3)Stay?\n";
    cin >> ans;

    if(ans == 1)
    {

    }

    if(ans == 2)        // Hit
    {

        Console::Clear();
        cout << "Your Hand\n";
        Player.AddCard(Deck.Draw());
        cout << "\nHand Value: " << Player.HandValue() << "\n";
        Player.Show();

        if(Player.HandValue() > 21)
        {
            cout << "You Busted man...Sorry :/\n\n"
                //<< "Dealer's Hand\n\n";
                //Dealer.Show();

        }

            else if(Player.HandValue() == 21)
            {
                cout << "You've Won Your Freedom! :D";
            }

        while( Dealer.HandValue() <= 17)
        {
            Dealer.AddCard(Deck.Draw());
            Dealer.Show(1);

            if(Dealer.HandValue() > 21)
            {
               cout << "Dealer Busted man...You Win! :D\n"
                    << "\nDealer's Hand\n";
                    Dealer.Show();
            }

            else if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21)
            {
                cout << "Dealer Wins...Your Soul! >:D\n"

            }

        }

    if(Player.HandValue() > Dealer.HandValue())
    {
        cout << "Your Hand Beats Dealer's...You Win!! :D\n"

    }

    else if(Player.HandValue() < Dealer.HandValue() && Dealer.HandValue() > 17 && Player.HandValue() > 17)
    {
        cout << "Dealer's Hand Wins...Sorry :/\n"

    }
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
    break;
if(ans == 3)        // Stay
{

    Console::Clear();
    cout << "Your Hand\n";
    cout << "\nHand Value: " << Player.HandValue() << "\n";
    Player.Show();

    if(Player.HandValue() > 21)
    {
        cout << "You Busted man...Sorry :/\n"

    }
    else if(Player.HandValue() == 21)
    {
        cout << "You've Won Your Freedom! :D\n";
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "Dealer's Hand\n";
        Dealer.Show();
    }
    while(Dealer.HandValue() < 17)
    {
        Dealer.AddCard(Deck.Draw());
        Dealer.Show(1);

    if(Dealer.HandValue() > 21)
    {
        cout << "Dealer Busted man...You Win! :D\n"

    }
    else if(Dealer.HandValue() == 21)
    {
        cout << "Dealer Wins...Your Soul! >:D\n"

    }
    }
    if(Player.HandValue() > Dealer.HandValue())
    {
        cout << "Your Hand Beats Dealer's...You Win!! :D\n"

    }
    else if(Player.HandValue() < Dealer.HandValue() && Dealer.HandValue() > 17 && Player.HandValue() > 17)
    {
        cout << "Dealer's Hand Wins...Sorry :/\n;
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}

if(ans == 4)
{
    exit(0);
}
system("pause");
}
```

Don't mind the if(ans == 1), I'm saving that for my betting code. This code does what I need it to, for the most part. I don't have something to check for aces yet. We have a stack for the deck, which is what the Draw() and AddCard() are pulling from. Any help is much appreciated, and be gentle with the comments, I am new. :)

Comment: Any particular problem..? We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: You say, "my game won't function right".  What input are you giving it?  What result are you seeing, and what result would you consider "right"?  (Or do you want us to totally guess?)

Comment: I had a feeling i was being too vague, sorry. This is part of a loop that i have going that, after it displays my hand and the dealer's hand, it asks if i want to bet, hit, or stay. I haven't been able to pinpoint it, but my problems all have to do with my outputs.

I tested it for a good couple of minutes, and this is the kind of trouble i am seeing:

Sometimes, if i draw, and then bust, the dealer still draws twice, then he busts, and both messages for bust, mine and his, display, so no one wins.

If i stay, i am automatically thrown back to my main menu, which isn't shown in the code.

Comment: ^ Should let dealer draw until he reaches his limit of 17, or he busts. 

Sometimes dealer draws once or twice, and the hand shows each time he draws. All on the same screen.

If dealer gets a better hand then me, it doesn't show his hand after mine.

Sometimes, if i win, the dealer still draws, and his hand shows.


These are my major problems, but i am sure there are more. Sorry for not being more specific earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You problem most likely stems from not handling some cases. Your code will fall through the tests if the players.HandValue() == dealers.HandValue(). Also there is no guarantee the player has < 17 (which you rely on in your tests).

I would suggest putting in an else {} clause and printing the players and dealers hand value's and a debug message to see what conditions you are missing, then you can try and work out why.

```
if(Player.HandValue() > Dealer.HandValue())
{
    cout << "Your Hand Beats Dealer's...You Win!! :D\n";
}
else if(Player.HandValue() < Dealer.HandValue() && Dealer.HandValue() > 17 && Player.HandValue() > 17)
{
    cout << "Dealer's Hand Wins...Sorry :/\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Unhandled case! Player handvalue: " << Player.HandValue() 
         << " dealer handvalue: " << Dealer.HandValue() << '\n';
}
```

HTH

Comment: I'll go ahead and try that. Do you think the while statement that i made so that my dealer would draw when he needs to might be making a problem?

Comment: Also, my stay function has no functionality, honestly. I have code for it, but i guess it never reaches my code for staying. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you want the program to work :) Thought you might want to put the while loop where the dealer draws cards into the stay branch. I would also factor out all the code that deals with figuring out who won into functions, like 'printGameResult()' or something similar.

Comment: If you are still having weird problems like you detailed, my first guess is that it would be the cin stream, perhaps you aren't always flushing them. Try clearing it immediately after it's read in (rather than in the if cases individually).